# Query to get all customers residing in same city

Tags: mysql, sql, grouping

I am trying to run simple query to get list of all customers staying in same city. Below is the table

```
CREATE TABLE `customers` (
  `customerNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `customerName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `contactLastName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `contactFirstName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `addressLine1` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `addressLine2` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `postalCode` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `salesRepEmployeeNumber` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `creditLimit` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`customerNumber`)
)
```

we have 3 users living in Auckland and 4 in New york but when i run below query

> 'GiftsForHim.com', 'Auckland' 
>  'Kelly's Gift Shop', 'Auckland'
> 'Gifts4AllAges.com', 'Boston'
>  'Diecast Collectables', 'Boston'

```
SELECT customerName,city FROM customers group by city
```

We get only single records , how does group by work and what would be the query to get list of customers residing in same city

> 'Down Under Souveniers, Inc', 'Auckland  '
> 'Gifts4AllAges.com', 'Boston'

Comment: You probably want `ORDER BY`, not `GROUP BY`.  Read up on `GROUP BY` here. https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx/

Comment: Please learn how to use `GROUP BY`.  It's not how to use it.

Comment: Same city as what?

Answer (score 2):

As it is unclear what you want, there might be two solutions.

```
Select customername, city from customers where city = ‘Auckland‘
```

Two get one row for each customer or

```
Select group_concat(customername, ‘, ‘), city from customers group by city
```

Comment: Its been a while that this solution was given but for those who are looking for SQL SERVER equivalent solution, I think we can use String_Agg() function available from version 2017 onwards.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group_concat()`

```
SELECT city ,group_concat(customerName) as all_customer
FROM customers group by city
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your answers may be my question was not clear i just wanted to list
all customers residing in same city , so order by clause solved the issue as suggested by O.Jones

```
SELECT city ,customerName FROM customers order by city
```

Answers provides Claus Bönnhoff and Fahmi were right too.